# Sum of series of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms

It’s from a STEP paper. How can I show this summation converges to give the answer required?

> $$1(\ln2-\ln1)+2(\ln3-\ln2)+\dots+(n-1)(\ln n-\ln(n-1))$$
>   which you can rearrange to give $n\ln n-\ln n!$ as required.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing your logarithmic laws, the expression is 
$$\ln\left(\frac{2^1}{1^1}\cdot\frac{3^2}{2^2}\cdot\frac{4^3}{3^3}\cdots\frac{n^{n-1}}{{(n-1)^{n-1}}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n^{n-1}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(n-1)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)$$
where we multiplied the numerator and denominator by $n$ as the last step.

This expression, again using logarithmic laws, is $n\ln(n)-\ln(n!)$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
S = 1(\ln2−\ln1)+2(\ln3−\ln2)+⋯+(n−1)(\ln n−\ln(n−1)) 
$$

Then,
$$\begin{align*}
S &= -\ln1 + (2-1)\cdot(-\ln2)+\dots+\big((n-1)-(n-2)\big)\cdot(-\ln (n-1)) + -\ln n + n\ln n \\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln i + n\ln n\\
&=-\ln(\prod_{i=1}^n i ) + n\ln n\\
&=-\ln(n!)+n\ln n
\end{align*}$$